# React useState with ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to create a form to save some form of data model in a database.

Let's say I have a class:

```
export default class Model {
    constructor(model = {}) {
        this.x = model.x || '';
        this.y = model.y || '';
    }
    save() {
        // code to save 'this' to database
    }

}
```

And a component:

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
   
export const ModelForm = () => {
    const [model, setModel] = useState(new Model());

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;

        setModel({ ...model, [target.name]: target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const modelObject = new Model(model);
        modelObject.save();
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' name='x' value={model.x} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <input type='text' name='y' value={model.y} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```

This thing is currently working, but I have a question.

Every time I do **setModel**, I have to destructure the **model** object and change the value accordingly. Since I destructure it, when I am submitting the form, the object in the component is no longer a **Model** object, but a simple javascript Object. So, as you can see, I have to create a new one to use **save()** on it.

Is my approach good or there is a better way to do it?

Also, is it a good practice to use ES6 classes in **useState**? Are there any downfalls?

Comment: I would change it so that `Model` is not responsible for the saving to database. I don't think the saving needs to be coupled to the model at all. It would also solve this 'problem' of having to re-create the `Model`

Comment: @nbokmans Ok, I understand. Other than that, is it a good practice to use ES6 classes in useState? Are there any downfalls?

Comment: no its bad idea!

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly why?

Comment: Because your state will change a lot  because functions are not primitives - react works on primitive state, and it will require component re-render

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Well, I use it just as a model to store data. I feel like it's easier to define a model class, than to create a custom object with key-value pairs in the component.

Comment: This might not be clearly visible when you have 1 method, but when you will have many class methods, they will all re-render component

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly So, I should define an object with the same fields as my Model class in the component and use it as init value in useState?

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Class methods don't change. And actually react doesn't do deep equality checks on state, so it won't even consider the methods - what matter is whether you pass a different instance or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my personal opinion, I don't think using ES6 classes in the state is a good idea. In fact, in the react useState hook documentation say that if you need to have two states on your component you should put two useState hooks.

```
// If there are too many states, you can use useReducer hook
const [state1, setState1] = useState();
const [state2, setState2] = useState();
```

I prefer use the useState hooks with primitives values, because as React works, when you change the state, if the value of the new state is equal to the old one, the component doesn't re-render because react do that comparison by itself, but when you use a object or any other non primitive value, even if the props of the object and values are the same, the reference to that object is going to be different, so it will re-render when it should not.
Remember that when JavaScript compares non primitive values it compares its references in memory so:

```
const obj1 = {prop: 'a'};
const obj2 = {prop: 'a'};
console.log(obj1 === obj2); // This logs false because they are different objects and they references in memory are not equal
console.log(obj1 === obj1); // This logs true, because its reference is the same.
console.log(obj1.prop === obj2.prop); // This logs true because they are strings (primitive values)
```

Comment: I got this, but what if we have a form with a lot of inputs? Using primitives to store each input's value looks pretty bad.

Comment: In components, where you need to manage a lot of states, you should use `useReducer`, this is the recommended way. But personally, in case of forms, I'd like to use other approach, It consists in using the useRef hook passing the reference to the inputs, and every time you change any of the inputs values, the form itself doesn't re-render (changing ref values don't triggers a re-render, the opposite happens with useState/useReducer), in the save button I access to input1ref.current.value, input2ref.current.value, ... and do a post request to save the form data.

Answer (score 3):

> I have to create a [`new Model`] to use `save()` on it.

That's certainly a viable approach. You wouldn't actually store a `Model` instance in your state, but only the options object for your constructor. Initialise it as simply

```
const [model, setModel] = useState({});
```

(and possibly rename it to `modelArgs` or `modelOptions`)

> Since I destructure it, […] the object in the component [state] is no longer a `Model` object, but a simple javascript Object.

It's actually not destructuring, rather object literal spread syntax, but yes - you're creating a plain object in your `setModel` call.

To fix the problem, you'd need to pass a model instance there - a new one, since React state is designed around immutability. You can easily achieve that though:

```
export default class Model {
    constructor(model = {}) {
        this.x = model.x || '';
        this.y = model.y || '';
    }
    withUpdate({name, value}) {
        // if (!['x', 'y'].includes(name)) throw new RangeError(…)
        return new Model({...this, [name]: value});
        // or optimised (?):
        const clone = new Model(this);
        clone[name] = value;
        return clone;
    }
    save() {
        // code to save 'this' to database
    }

}
```

```
const [model, setModel] = useState(new Model());
const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setModel(model.withUpdate(event.target));
};
```

Comment: You think it's a good practice to create a new object every time an input changes?

Comment: @Ghost React requires a new object every time you want to update the state. Whether this is a plain object or a `Model` instance doesn't make much of a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it is very usefull to have es6 classes in your state sometimes. A decent solution is just to create a derived variable.

```
import { React, useState } from 'react';
   
export const ModelForm = () => {
    const [_model, setModel] = useState({});
    const model = new Model(_model)

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const target = event.target;

        setModel({ ...model, [target.name]: target.value });
    };

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const modelObject = new Model(model);
        modelObject.save();
    };

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input type='text' name='x' value={model.x} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <input type='text' name='y' value={model.y} onChange={handleInputChange} />
            <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
        </form>
    );
};
```